# Adding a Ruby Block in html to an input class - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a ruby block to a span class with in an HTML file.

```
<%= f.label :email =>
```

The div & span class are as follows:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    <input class="span" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

I have placed the ruby block inside the the input class:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    <input class="span <%= f.text_field :email %>" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, is this the correct way of placing ruby blocks inside of divs/spans/or input tags?

What I am trying to do is add an icon to an input field.  It does work, when I submit the text.  It just looks wierd, the code and the actual object.

Comment: Have you tried running that? Don't think it's what you intend. What that would do is output an `<input>` inside your `<span>`'s class attribute, which is not going to work. Please update your question to describe what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this may be what you're after:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :id => "prependedInput" %>
</div>
```

Comment: This partially works, the problem is the text field width is too small and the length is to long.  Also, it looks different in safari form FF.

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question, really. But if you have a look at the bootstrap documentation you'll find you can adjust the size of the field by adding a class to the text field.